# mod_spdy: Browsers which not support the SPDY protocol

Tags: browser, spdy

I have a doubt about using module mod_spdy in my webite:

If I install the module mod_spdy in my Apache Server, What will it happen with the http requests come from desktop and mobile browser which not support the SPDY protocol? (see the  browser which not support the SPDY protocol in http://caniuse.com/spdy )

I don’t know if in this case Apache will serve the information using the http protocol or the web browser will have problem to render the information. In the last case, is there any solution to solve the problem with the browser that not support SPDY? For instance, use a web server responding with a different protocol (http or SPDY) depending on which user agent is requesting: browsers support SPDY or browsers only support HTTP.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First of all Apache mod_SPDY supports encrypted connection(HTTPS) only, therefore you have to create a VirtualHost for the 443 port and add your SSL certificate. Mod_SPDY will automatically fallback to HTTPS 1.1 if the browser does not support SPDY. A good use for it is to enable server PUSH. Have fun with SPDY!